# Identify Sci Fi Story that had wanted posters and yellow chalked signs

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to identify Sci Fi Story that had wanted posters and yellow chalked signs. I remember there was a boy who was told by a new boarder to report about but avoid strange men/beings who were in large cars or taxis. The boy has to travel to a seedy pool hall to place a bet for the boarder.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Novel? Short story? Movie? TV show? Stage play? Opera? Comic book? You saw it 5 years ago, 50 years ago? What was science-fictional about it? Did it have Martians, ray guns, space ships, time machines, zombies?

Comment: More details are required here, can you remember anything else at all?  Check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Possibly "Low Men In Yellow Coats" from Stephen King's "Hearts In Atlantis"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by starpilotsix this does sound a bit like [Low Men in Yellow Coats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearts_in_Atlantis#Low_Men_in_Yellow_Coats) by Stephen King, though it's a novella not a story.

The boy is Bobby Garfield. By *boarder* I guess you mean *lodger*, in which case he is Ted (I don't think we find out his surname). Ted is being hunted by strange men known as the Low Men and Bobby helps him.

The wanted posters are actually posters about lost pets. Ted tells Bobby:

> “On your travels around town, keep an eye out for lost-pet posters on walls, in shop windows, stapled to telephone poles on residential streets. ‘Lost, a gray tabby cat with black ears, a white bib, and a crooked tail. Call IRoquois 7-7661.’ ‘Lost, a small mongrel dog, part beagle, answers to the name of Trixie, loves children, ours want her to come home. Call IRoquois 7-0984 or bring to 77 Peabody Street.’ That sort of thing.”

The yellow chalk signs are in the novella though a yellow chalk sign is only mentioned once. The signs are in other colours as well. Ted asks Bobby to watch for the signs:

> Good so far, very good. Now—you know the hopscotch patterns kids are always drawing on the sidewalks?”
>   Bobby nodded.
>   “Look for ones with stars or moons or both chalked near them, usually in chalk of a different color.
>   
>   ...
>   
>   “Oh no, oh no, I don’t believe it, you gotta be kidding.” He reached out toward the star and the crescent moon—they were drawn in yellow chalk, not purple—almost touched them, then drew his hand back.

At one point in the story Ted and Bobby go to a pool hall where Ted places a bet on boxing match.

Comment: Thank you all. Low Men In Yellow Coats" from Stephen King's "Hearts In Atlantis" is it. Also, thanks for the tips on making the search better.